# How to send Python line graph output through HDMI to another display?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, display, hdmi

I am working on a project that need me to generate a real time line chart on a separate display.

I'm able to have the real time line chart working on my laptop now but I also want the separate display to show only the line chart (the chart window only), I do not want to make the display as the duplicate of my laptop screen. Is there a way for me to do send the chart through HDMI using Python? Is there any library/ function that would be helpful? If Python won't work, is there any other tool that could be helpful for my case?

Feel free to let me know if you have any question regarding this scenario, any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a graph with matplotlib. Save it to a specific location with some name.

Then use PyGame/ Tkinter/ PyQt5 to make a "window" to display the image.

Then extend your display. The projector display will have the PyGame/PyQt "window" in full-screen.

I think this is pretty much what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the comment UJJAVAL! Just to follow up that the project I am doing actually requires me to use Python to communicate with the HDMI port, so that I can send my graph output directly through the port to the display, is there a way you can think of to achieve that?